# Response content-type text/html on server but application/json locally

Tags: httpresponse, httpcontext, jsonresult

I am extending the JsonResult class

```
    public class MyRequest : JsonResult
    {
        private readonly string _statusDescription;

        public MyRequest (object data)
            : this(data, "My Request")
        {
        }

        public MyRequest (object data, string description)
        {
            Data = data;
            _statusDescription = description;
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription = _statusDescription;
            base.ExecuteResult(context);
        }
    }
```

When I use this class locally to return an object I get my json object and content-type = json.

But when I run this on the server I get content-type = text/html. On the server the text value is "My Request" which is the description and there is no json value returned.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might learn more by looking at the headers returned by your request, `postman` is a great tool to use for this kind of problem (others tools are available!)

Comment: reponse.headers.get("content-type") is what i use to check my response during the fetch.